# write dataframe to .xlsx too slow

Tags: pandas

I have a 40MB dataframe 'dfScore' I am writing to .xlsx。
[image]
the code is as follow,

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dfScore.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

the code `dfScore.to_excel`  take almost an hour ,`the code writer.save()`  takes another hour. Is this normal? Is there a good way to take less than 10 min?

i already searched in stackoverflow ,but it seems some suggestions not working on my problem.

Comment: The size of your dataframe is 4 million rows by 5 columns. Try writing to csv and compare times.

Comment: Modern excel spreadsheets can only handle 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: It is not too slow, it is stuck. It is dead. You are writing more rows than excel can handle. And that is causing the excel writer to silently but indefinitely wait for a miracle, which will never happen. Either split your dataframe into bits and write them as separate sheets, or use another format (csv for instance), or compress your dataframe using some statistical tools to make it fit into excel.

Comment: On 8 GB, macbook air - reading and writing 2 milion records to excel takes ~20 mins and just 49 seconds to write csv and 19 seconds to read back csv. Use excel as explained in answer

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you save it as .csv?
I have worked with heavier DataFrames on my personal laptop and I had the same problem with writing to xlsx.

```
your_dataframe.to_csv('my_file.csv',encoding='utf-8',columns=list_of_dataframe_columns)
```

then you can simply convert it to .xlsx with MS Excel or an online convertor.

Comment: I have consistently noted the same slowness and worked around it in this way - save to csv then just open in Excel and re-save as xlsx. Many times faster to do it this way. Unfortunately, I don't know the reason why.

Comment: I cannot do this in my case as in 2 of columns are written in Arabic language..Arabic is not opening properly in CSVs

Answer (score 0):

> the code dfScore.to_excel take almost an hour ,the code writer.save() takes another hour. Is this normal?

That sounds a bit too high. I ran an XlsxWriter test writing 1,000,000 rows x 5 columns and it took ~ 100s. The time will vary based on the CPU and Memory of the test machine but 1 hour is 36 times slower which doesn't seem right.

Note, Excel, and thus XlsxWriter, only supports 1,048,576 rows per worksheet so you are effectively throwing away 3/4s of your data and wasting time doing it.

> Is there a good way to take less than 10 min?

For pure XlsxWriter programs [pypy](http://pypy.org/) gives a good speed up. For example rerunning my 1,000,000 rows x 5 columns testcase with pypy the time went from 99.15s to 16.49s. I don't know if Pandas works with pypy though.