# Python code takes too long to print data frames / finish the process

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

The code below aims to copy the data from multiple files and paste it in the master file.
But it takes too long (apx 10 min) to print the dfs ( currently I have 3  *.xlsb files, size are between 2k - 6k kb ranges, data on 70k rows in each file).

Im beginner in coding and could not manage to use Profiling technique to analyze the execution process.

Could I improve it somehow that it does not take this long?

```
import pandas as pd

from calendar import month_name
from pathlib import Path

filenames_array = [f'PB orders {m[:3]}.xlsx' for m in month_name[1:]]
masterfile_sheetname_array = [f'{m[:3]}data' for m in month_name[1:]]
my_path= Path("C:").resolve() / 'Load_attachments'



for filename in my_path.glob('*.xlsx'):
    print(filename)
    month = pd.read_excel(str(filename), sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="openpyxl")
    print(month, end='\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
    with pd.ExcelWriter(
            my_path.parent / 'PB report.xlsx',
            mode="a",
            if_sheet_exists="replace",
            engine="openpyxl",
    ) as writer:
        month.to_excel(
            writer,
            sheet_name=masterfile_sheetname_array[
                filenames_array.index(filename.name)
            ],  # Since the lists share the same indeces, use the filename to retrieve the name of the sheet
            engine="openpyxl",
            index=False,
        )
```

Comment: For starters, I suppose you can try separating your loop into two loops: one just for reading from file, and one just for writing to disk. If you print the datetime in between, you can get a rough idea on what part of your code is slow and needs work.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using csv format instead of excel which is historically very slow both in writing and reading

see this link : [write dataframe to .xlsx too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987767/write-dataframe-to-xlsx-too-slow)

Comment: I get the files from the sales department (xlsb format, multiple sheets, but I use only one sheet). So not sure what to do in that case.

Comment: Lorenzo is referring to save as CSV here instead of save as Excel

Comment: When there are multiple sheets in the file excel does not support to save it as CSV

Comment: Maybe try to get the names of your sheets as a list (fieldnames for exemple), then use a for loop : "for col in fieldnames:
    df[col].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=col)" then use writer.save() after your for loop