# Editing dataframe and exporting to excel in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

Following is a simplified example of data I have in csv file format. Data from sensor A extends from column 1 to column 3 & sensor B from column 4 onwards.

| Tool | Time A[s] | Val1 | time B [s] | Val11 | Val22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZED112 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2.406871364 | 2.825639219 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2.598295494 | 3.047110501 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2.532422572 | 2.708097541 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2.780893807 | 2.678502954 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3.202879068 | 3.062976324 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 973.9316 | 0 | 2.784906006 | 2.642870937 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 985.1649 | 0 | 214.2264642 | 98.62286259 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 992.4298 | 0 | 414.5566632 | 217.3663605 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 995.9097 | 0 | 599.8237339 | 315.2468997 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 997.9854 | 0.3 | 643.9497261 | 399.9559597 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 997.7411 | 0.8 | 524.0249116 | 328.1903351 |
| ZED112 | 0 | 991.8193 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0 | 999.5726 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.1 | 999.2064 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.2 | 999.939 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.3 | 999.6948 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.4 | 996.2759 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.5 | 999.1453 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.6 | 999.8779 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.7 | 1000.427 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.8 | 1000.549 |  |  |  |

1)How can I delete rows in column 1 to 3 which correspond to Time A[s]==0, while keeping data from column 4 onwards intact.
2) The following is just a snippet of data and actual data is hundreds of columns long. What is the most efficient way of exporting to excel after performing action 1?
3) My final end goal after exporting to excel is to rearrange data like below(currently doing manually), such that data of same time is on same row. I don't know how to accomplish this right now. Any suggestions?

| Tool | Time A[s] | Val1 | time B [s] | Val11 | Val22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZED112 | 0.1 | 999.2064 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.2 | 999.939 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.2 | 999.939 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.3 | 999.6948 | 0.3 | 643.9497261 | 399.9559597 |
| ZED112 | 0.4 | 996.2759 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.5 | 999.1453 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.6 | 999.8779 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.7 | 1000.427 |  |  |  |
| ZED112 | 0.8 | 1000.549 | 0.8 | 524.0249116 | 328.1903351 |

My solution for 1 & 2 is below, but this isn't giving me expected result. Also excel export of "real data" is taking extremely long time.

```
    import pandas as pd
    alldata= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\max\Desktop\Input data.csv");
    df2 = alldata.iloc[: , 3:-1].copy();
    df1 = alldata.drop(alldata.columns[3:-1], axis=1);
    newdata=df1[df1[' Time sensor A[s]'] != 0];
    result=pd.concat([newdata,df2], axis=1, join="inner");
    result.to_excel(r"C:\Users\max\Desktop\data2.xlsx",)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you can slice the data into 2 parts and easily fulfill your requirement. Here is how:

```
#reading the data
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\max\Desktop\Input data.csv");

#copying the first & last 3 columns in variables dfA and dfB respectively
dfA=df.iloc[:,:3]
dfB= df.iloc[:,3:]

#droping the values corresponding to Time A[s]==0
dfA= dfA[dfA['Time A[s]']!=0].reset_index(drop=True)

#merging dfA and dfB back again as per your final requirement
result=pd.merge(dfA,dfB, how='left',left_on=['Time A[s]'],right_on=['time B [s]'])

#exporting the data to excel
result.to_excel(r"C:\Users\max\Desktop\data2.xlsx",)
```

You can print the variables dfA,dfB, and the result after each step to get better clarity.

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped achieve what I wanted. I still have the problem of excel output. My csv file is around 70Mb, (700 columns & 20k rows) in size and the program I have based on your code takes about 9mins to execute.

Comment: @AP85' I searched and encountered a few approaches like exporting to .csv instead of excel or dividing the dataframe into 2 or 4 parts before exporting but I believe, out there, 
 better techniques are waiting for both of us. But for comparison, it took the user [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987767/write-dataframe-to-xlsx-too-slow)1 hour to export 40MB Dataframe in 2016 against your 9 mins of  70MB csv (probably too large for excel to handle).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to merge your data and then drop the rows that have 0 for `Time A[s]`. I also changed the name of your columns for testing because spaces in pandas column names are very problematic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Tool"," Time A[s]","Val1"," time B[s]","Val11","Val22"],
                  data=[["ZED112"   ,0      ,0      ,0      ,2.406871364    ,2.825639219]
                        ,["ZED112"  ,0      ,0      ,0      ,2.598295494    ,3.047110501]
                        ,["ZED112"  ,0.1        ,999.2064, "", "", ""]
                        ,["ZED112"  ,0.2        ,999.939, "", "", ""]
                        ,["ZED112"  ,0.3        ,999.6948, "", "", ""]  
                        ,["ZED112"  ,0      ,997.9854   ,0.3        ,643.9497261    ,399.9559597],
                        ["ZED112"   ,0      ,997.9854   ,0.3        ,643.9497261    ,399.9559597]],
)
# df= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\max\Desktop\Input data.csv");
df
```

Output:

```
    Tool    Time A[s]   Val1     time B[s]  Val11   Val22
0   ZED112  0.0          0.0000    0        2.406871    2.825639
1   ZED112  0.0          0.0000    0        2.598295    3.047111
2   ZED112  0.1          999.2064           
3   ZED112  0.2          999.9390           
4   ZED112  0.3          999.6948           
5   ZED112  0.0          997.9854  0.3      643.949726  399.95596
6   ZED112  0.0          997.9854  0.3      643.949726  399.95596
```

---

```
# Change the name of columns for merging
df1 = df.iloc[:,0:2].rename(columns={" Time A[s]":"time"})
df2 = df.iloc[:,3:].rename(columns={" time B[s]":"time"})

# You can't merge on floats so change the datatype to str
df1 = df1.astype({'time':'str'})
df2 = df2.astype({'time':'str'})

# Merge on the time column
results = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='time')

results['time']=results['time'].replace(0, np.nan)
results.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
results
```

Output:

```
Tool    time    Val11   Val22
0   ZED112  0.3 643.949726  399.95596
1   ZED112  0.3 643.949726  399.95596
```

Comment: The code you suggested doesn't seem to work. The code throws error in the step
`df1 = df1.astype({'time':'str'})`. Also, based on the results you showed it looks like some data will be lost, where Time A[s]!=0.