# Pandas not writing the dataframe to excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, openpyxl

I have a dataframe with some 40K records(certainly not exceeding the maximum limit) , I could see the dataframe as well in my console but it fails to write it in my given excel though it was created, it always shows 0 kb. i am using pandas v 2.0.

-I have a dataframe with some 40K records(certainly not exceeding the maximum limit) , I could see the dataframe as well in my console but it fails to write it in my given excel though it was created, it always shows 0 kb. i am using pandas v 2.0.

expecting the dataframe will be write to excel.

I have used copy().to_clipboard() method to manually copy and verify the data.

not sure how to resolve, any help here?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If it shows 0 Kb with no error output, you should try refreshing the file system and keep waiting. The excel conversion is known to take a long time under some circumstances. See here:

[write dataframe to .xlsx too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987767/write-dataframe-to-xlsx-too-slow)

As suggested, I would recommend trying to export to CSV and see if that will be faster.